# How can I define variables that are not used like types?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tuples

I have a code written in Visual Studio 2017.
Now I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2015, but Tuple installation failed.
So I'm coding without using Tuple.

This code

```
namespace TEST00
{
    public class Class1<T> : IValueConverter
    {
        public T ValueForTrue { get; set; }

        public T ValueForFalse { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool v = new bool();
            bool v1 = (value is v) && v;
            return v1 ? ValueForTrue : ValueForFalse;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

causes

> CS0118 : 'v' is a variable but is used like a type

Original code in Visual Studio 2017 is

```
namespace TEST00
{
    public class Class1<T> : IValueConverter
    {
        public T ValueForTrue { get; set; }

        public T ValueForFalse { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((value is bool v) && v) ? ValueForTrue : ValueForFalse;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and it works.

I don't know how to define 'v'.
How can I define variables that are not used like types?

Comment: There are no tuples in your code anywhere. Not sure what that had to do with the question which is about type conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
    bool v1 = (value is bool) && (bool)value;
```

Comment: or maybe `return (value as bool?) == true ? ValueForTrue : ValueForFalse`

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity and TheGeneral! Two methods are helpful!